# How to use foreach loop to display [offer] from this multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$result = Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [@attributes] => Array(
                [id] => 1
                [name] => New
        )

        [offer] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [merchant_id] => 63
                        [merchant_name] => merchantExpr
                        [price] => $36

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [merchant_id] => 43
                        [merchant_name] => merchantRex
                        [price] => 32
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [merchant_id] => 17
                        [merchant_name] => Bexrest
                        [price] => 13.60
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [merchant_id] => 4
                        [merchant_name] => bnt
                        [price] => 13.72
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

How to display [offer] array by using foreach loop?

Comment: Documentation ftw : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: `@attributes` suggests this is originally from a SimpleXML object, which have a very simple interface (although that's not always immediately obvious). Can you post what you've tried please?

Comment: <?php echo $booksof[0]['offer'][0]['merchant_id']; ?>
By using this code can I show merchant value. But I can't use it inside foreach loop.

Comment: because $booksof[0]['offer'][0]['merchant_id']; isn't an array, if you want to loop you can use $booksof[0]['offer']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
foreach($array[0]['offer'] as $data)
{
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key . ' -----> ' . $value . '<br/>';  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working great :). 
I used to get single [offer] value by using this code.

foreach( $array[0]['offer'] as $data ){
    echo $data['merchant_name'] . '<br/>';  
}